# Reading Time(Ds1307) using I2C

Tags: c, i2c, mplab

I'm using PIC18F45K22 and XC8.
I have insert MCC library for I2C

I need example to read seconds from ds1307 and in next level to change current time.

Acording to code below, i'm stack inside
while (status == I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING);

```
    I2C2_MasterWrite(&pdata_write, 1, 0b11010000, &status);
 // at this point, your status will probably be I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING
    while (status == I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING); // wait for status to to change
    if (status == I2C2_MESSAGE_COMPLETE) {
    I2C2_MasterRead(&pdata_read, 1, 0b11010001, &status);
    while (status == I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING); // again, wait for status to to change
    if (status == I2C2_MESSAGE_COMPLETE) {
        // pdata_read should now be the number of seconds (in binary-coded decimal)
    }
```

here is my pin manager auto created from mcc

```
#define SCL2_TRIS               TRISDbits.TRISD0
#define SCL2_LAT                LATDbits.LATD0
#define SCL2_PORT               PORTDbits.RD0
#define SCL2_ANS                ANSELDbits.ANSD0
#define SCL2_SetHigh()            do { LATDbits.LATD0 = 1; } while(0)
#define SCL2_SetLow()             do { LATDbits.LATD0 = 0; } while(0)
#define SCL2_Toggle()             do { LATDbits.LATD0 = ~LATDbits.LATD0; } while(0)
#define SCL2_GetValue()           PORTDbits.RD0
#define SCL2_SetDigitalInput()    do { TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 1; } while(0)
#define SCL2_SetDigitalOutput()   do { TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0; } while(0)
#define SCL2_SetAnalogMode()  do { ANSELDbits.ANSD0 = 1; } while(0)
#define SCL2_SetDigitalMode() do { ANSELDbits.ANSD0 = 0; } while(0)

// get/set SDA2 aliases
#define SDA2_TRIS               TRISDbits.TRISD1
#define SDA2_LAT                LATDbits.LATD1
#define SDA2_PORT               PORTDbits.RD1
#define SDA2_ANS                ANSELDbits.ANSD1
#define SDA2_SetHigh()            do { LATDbits.LATD1 = 1; } while(0)
#define SDA2_SetLow()             do { LATDbits.LATD1 = 0; } while(0)
#define SDA2_Toggle()             do { LATDbits.LATD1 = ~LATDbits.LATD1; } while(0)
#define SDA2_GetValue()           PORTDbits.RD1
#define SDA2_SetDigitalInput()    do { TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 1; } while(0)
#define SDA2_SetDigitalOutput()   do { TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 0; } while(0)
#define SDA2_SetAnalogMode()  do { ANSELDbits.ANSD1 = 1; } while(0)
#define SDA2_SetDigitalMode() do { ANSELDbits.ANSD1 = 0; } while(0)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoNSC.jpg)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Puod.jpg)

See pictures below

Also trying to show time in my lcd

```
sprintf(txt,"%d",pdata_read);
     LCDPutStr(txt,1);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm stack inside"? Did your code get stuck?

Comment: My code doesnt go out from this loop while (status == I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING);

Comment: Should i check for hardware errors? Also i noticed that mcc auto generated both my pins scl and sda are configured both as inputs. Is this right?

Comment: Hmm, his means that the message is stuck in "pending". Odd. I don't have the software or the hardware, so I don't really have an answer. But you could be right about it being a configuration issue. "SCL" should be clock, which should be provided by the microcontroller. Calling this an "input" seems odd to me. "SDA" is the data line, which can be input or output.

Comment: I can send you every information you want see, i'm just want to solve this.Also check upload images. Is there possibility to have wrong speed in mssp?

Comment: Oh yes, the datasheet says the maximum SCL is 100 KHz (page 3)

Comment: I change it to standard speed and sda hold time to 300ns and frequency to 0xFF 15.625Khz but my code is inside this loop again

Comment: Are you sure that we dont need to send a start bit first?

Comment: Sorry, I can't be 100% sure... Did you manage to set the correct frequency and set the pin(s) as input and output?

Comment: Yes, according to datasheet i have set speed to 100khz. I didnt made any change in my pins cause mcc auto set both of them as input. Maybe it handles their position. I need to ask is the order right? i mean according this site https://www.studentcompanion.co.za/interfacing-the-ds1307-real-time-clock-with-pic-microcontroller-xc8/, we need to sent first start bit, then adress and then the register... We make the opposite, does this influence are ds1307?

Comment: Do i need i2c drivers and types from mcc?

Comment: Do you want to give you teamviewer for taking a look?

Comment: Should i send in read also register example for seconds?

Comment: Okay, so I installed the software. When I right-click the SDA/SCL pins in the pin manager, I get a small pop-up that says "MSSP2 | SDA2 | in/out"/"MSSP2 | SCL2 | in/out". If you get "in" for both, that seems wrong to me.

Comment: Regarding "we need to sent first start bit, then adress and then the register... We make the opposite" <-- I think we're doing the same. `I2C_MasterWrite` should handle the low-level stuff like start/addressing/acknowledging

Comment: Also sorry, I don't think I can be of much further help, not having any hardware and using the software for the first time in my life today. Let us know when you figure it all out! I'm sure you'll find something

Comment: One last question which is not clear to me. For sending seconds do i need register example 0x00 and data 0x50== 50''. Cause in your example how can ds1307 understand that 0 is id pdata_write going for seconds or for minitues?The same question going also for reading

Comment: Sorry, I may have made a bad mistake. I think you have to make the addresses `0b110100` (just 7 bits, so without the trailing `0` and `1`. It's likely that the `I2C_MasterRead`/`I2C_MasterWrite` functions will append the final `0`/`1` (to indicate write/read) for you.

Comment: As for your last question: page 8 of the datasheet shows which register is where. "Seconds" is register 0, "minutes" is register 1, "hours" is register 2.

Comment: Yes but how you tell in code go to register 0 and make second 10? in other example thay have i2c_Send(0x00,0x10);

Comment: Stack again inside while (status == I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING);

Comment: Updated my answer with a snippet for writing

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the hardware or the software, but had a look at https://www.studentcompanion.co.za/interfacing-the-ds1307-real-time-clock-with-pic-microcontroller-xc8/ (a long tutorial that might get you up to speed) and https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf (the datasheet), as well as some random pages that mentioned `I2C_MasterWrite`/`I2C_MasterRead` somehow.

The very low-level steps are:

1. START (handled for you)
2. Write 0b1101000 (this is an address plus the direction bit)
3. Receive ACKNOWLEDGE
4. Write address of "seconds" register, which as you correctly stated is `0x00` (this is data)
5. Receive ACKNOWLEDGE
6. START
7. Write 0b11010001 (this is an address plus the direction bit)
8. Receive ACKNOWLEDGE
9. Read
10. Send ACKNOWLEDGE or Not Acknowledge

It looks like the very low-level parts (START/ACKNOWLEDGE and sending addresses) are being handled for you, so you probably only have to do something similar to the following code (you may want to restructure the `if` logic to handle errors better however):

```
I2C_MESSAGE_STATUS status;
uint8_t pdata_write = 0; // 0 to 'seconds' register
uint8_t pdata_read; // will hold 'seconds'

I2C2_MasterWrite(&pdata_write, 1, 0b1101000, &status);
// at this point, your status will probably be I2C2_MESSAGE_PENDING
while (status == I2C_MESSAGE_PENDING); // wait for status to to change
if (status == I2C_MESSAGE_COMPLETE) {
    I2C2_MasterRead(&pdata_read, 1, 0b1101000, &status);
    while (status == I2C_MESSAGE_PENDING); // again, wait for status to to change
    if (status == I2C_MESSAGE_COMPLETE) {
        // pdata_read should now be the number of seconds (in binary-coded decimal)
    }
}
```

- `*pdata` is a pointer to what you would like to read/write, which would indeed be a pointer to a variable that has `0x0` in it in step 4 above.
- `length` is the length of the data you would like to read/write, which I think happens to be 1 in all steps listed above
- `address` is the address of the DS1307, `0b1101000`
- `pstatus` is the status of the I2C message.

According to https://github.com/apaivaj/WWVB/blob/master/MainProject/WWVB/mcc_generated_files/i2c1.h, `pstatus` can be any of the following:

```
typedef enum
{
    I2C1_MESSAGE_FAIL,
    I2C1_MESSAGE_PENDING,
    I2C1_MESSAGE_COMPLETE,
    I2C1_STUCK_START,
    I2C1_MESSAGE_ADDRESS_NO_ACK,
    I2C1_DATA_NO_ACK,
    I2C1_LOST_STATE
} I2C1_MESSAGE_STATUS;
```

You should probably check for at least `I2C_MESSAGE_FAIL`.

---

**Update**: To write into the seconds register, see figure 4 on page 12 of the datasheet: you need to write two pieces of data: first the register number, and then the number you would like to write into that register. Thus, the code would look like this:

```
I2C_MESSAGE_STATUS status;
uint8_t pdata_write[2] = { 0, 0x10 }; // 0x10 into 'seconds' register
I2C2_MasterWrite(pdata_write, 1, 0b1101000, &status);
while (status == I2C_MESSAGE_PENDING); // wait for status to to change
if (status == I2C_MESSAGE_COMPLETE) {
    // done!
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but i cant understand how can i use void below void I2C2_MasterWrite(
                                uint8_t *pdata,
                                uint8_t length,
                                uint16_t address,
                                I2C2_MESSAGE_STATUS *pstatus);

Comment: How should i send just a bit for clearing write and get Ack using code above??

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. Can you edit your original question and add your new questions?

Comment: Same proble again stacking inside while.Dont you have a very easy eample how to send and read from i2c?Something like this http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorial

Comment: http://www.microchip.com/forums/m927753.aspx Maybe this helps somehow? (See attachment on first comment)